# How to disable or enable button with Alpine js

Tags: html, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I have this increment and decrement dropdown on my page. I want to add a max-min value to it, and when the max or min value is reached, I what my button to be disabled.

I am new to Alpine.
If you have any suggestions for my code, I will be pleased and open to them, and I would appreciate it.

```
<!-- Occupancy -->
<div class="relative md:w-auto w-full">
    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div
            x-data="{
                open: false,
                total: 0,
                incrementTotal() {
                    this.total++;
                },
                decrementTotal() {
                    this.total--;
                },
                toggle() {
                    if (this.open) {
                        return this.close()
                    }

                    this.$refs.button.focus()

                    this.open = true
                },
                close(focusAfter) {
                    if (! this.open) return

                    this.open = false

                    focusAfter && focusAfter.focus()
                }
            }"
            x-on:keydown.escape.prevent.stop="close($refs.button)"
            x-on:focusin.window="! $refs.panel.contains($event.target) && close()"
            x-id="['dropdown-button']"
            class="relative w-full"
        >
            <!-- Button -->
            <button
                x-ref="button"
                x-on:click="toggle()"
                :aria-expanded="open"
                :aria-controls="$id('dropdown-button')"
                type="button"
                class="flex items-center gap-2 bg-white px-15 md:py-20 py-18 md:w-[90px] w-full rounded-md shadow flex-row"
            >
                <div class="flex flex-row space-x-16">
                    <x-icons.user-account class="w-24 h-24 text-black cursor-pointer" />
                    <div class="text-base text-left">
                        <span x-text="total" class="w-[30px] text-center" :value="total"></span> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </button>

            <!-- Panel -->
            <div
                x-ref="panel"
                x-show="open"
                x-transition.origin.top.left
                x-on:click.outside="close($refs.button)"
                :id="$id('dropdown-button')"
                style="display: none;"
                class="absolute right-0 md:top-full top-[90%] mt-16 p-24 z-50 md:w-[300px] w-full rounded-md bg-white shadow-2xl space-y-24"
            >
                <div class="font-bold text-2xl text-black text-left">
                    <p>Heading here</p>
                </div>
                <div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-center w-full" x-data="{ number: 0 }">
                    <div class="flex flex-col text-base text-black w-full">
                        <p>Something</p>
                        <div class="text-gray-700">
                            <p>Something else</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex space-x-8 items-center md:justify-center justify-end w-full text-base" x-data="{ count: 1, buttonDisabled: false }" x-modelable="count" x-model="number">
                        <button class="rounded-full border-1 border-gray-700 p-10" @click="count--; decrementTotal(); if(total < 1){total = 1; buttonDisabled = true} else{buttonDisabled = false}" x-bind:disabled="buttonDisabled"><x-icons.minus class="w-16 h-16"/></button>
                        <span x-text="number" class="w-[30px] text-center" required min="1" max="6" :value="total"></span>
                        <button class="rounded-full border-1 border-gray-700 p-10" @click="count++; incrementTotal(); if(total > 6){total = 6; buttonDisabled = true} else{buttonDisabled = false}" x-bind:disabled="buttonDisabled"><x-icons.plus-add class="w-16 h-16"/></button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
 <div class="flex flex-row justify-between items-center w-full" x-data="{ number: 0 }">
                    <div class="flex flex-col text-base text-black w-full">
                        <p>Something 2</p>
                        <div class="text-gray-700">
                            <p>Something else 2</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex space-x-8 items-center md:justify-center justify-end w-full text-base" x-data="{ count: 1, buttonDisabled: false }" x-modelable="count" x-model="number">
                        <button class="rounded-full border-1 border-gray-700 p-10" @click="count--; decrementTotal(); if(total < 1){total = 1; buttonDisabled = true} else{buttonDisabled = false}" x-bind:disabled="buttonDisabled"><x-icons.minus class="w-16 h-16"/></button>
                        <span x-text="number" class="w-[30px] text-center" required min="1" max="6" :value="total"></span>
                        <button class="rounded-full border-1 border-gray-700 p-10" @click="count++; incrementTotal(); if(total > 6){total = 6; buttonDisabled = true} else{buttonDisabled = false}" x-bind:disabled="buttonDisabled"><x-icons.plus-add class="w-16 h-16"/></button>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my code after one click the button is disabled.